# Practically and probabilistically modeling discrete data that can take on a countable (potentially infinite) number of values?

Tags: modeling, continuous-data, discrete-data, many-categories, application

As an example, let's say that we have observations of the price of some good at various points in time and would like to predict the distribution of the price of the good one point in the future from the current price. Note that we are ignoring the implications of stationarity or non-stationarity and evenly or unevenly-spaced-in-time observations for the sake of this question.

I know that price is commonly modeled as a continuous random variable, but perhaps we want to model it as a discrete random variable since we commonly observe prices delineated in increments of, at minimum, $0.01.

In practice, what options do we have for addressing the situation when our input and output variables can take on a countably infinite/extremely large number of values?

Is this just a situation where we would overwhelmingly go with just modeling it as a continuous variable for tractability as the impact of any biases introduced by this would almost always be much smaller than attempting to do something such as a multinomial regression with an **extremely** large number of possible input and output values?

Comment: most regression models are predicting the expected value (conditioned on the input). The conditional expectation of a discrete variable is most likely real, so no bias is even introduced for the output

Comment: @seanv507 Ah yes, that is a good point, I think I had in mind a probabilistic prediction, I'll include that in the oriiginal question, thanks!

Comment: a multinomial dist in such a case is an awful idea, because that model would not realize that \$2.01 is similar to \$2.00; they would just be two outcomes of all possible outcomes. This is why we have discrete distributions like the Poisson distribution.

Comment: Fair point @JohnMadden that makes sense.

Comment: For some reason, the idea of commonly used distributions with countable support passed me by.